# Fill NaN Column with Other Column Values, Duplicates New Row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, nan

I have a bit of a perplexing operation to try to accomplish efficiently on a dataset with the following general formal:

```
id,date,ind_1,ind_2,ind_3,ind_4
1,2014-01-01,ind_1,NaN,NaN,NaN
2,2014-01-02,ind_1,NaN,ind_3,NaN
3,2014-01-03,ind_1,ind_2,ind_3,NaN
```

I am trying to figure out how I can create a new column "ind_all" that is filled with any non-null "ind" column.  That is simple enough.  I can use .idxmax().  However, the tricky part is that I can have multiple "ind" per row.  This means I need to create a new record when there are duplicates.  The above example should end up looking like this in the end:

```
id,date,ind_1,ind_2,ind_3,ind_4,ind_all
1,2014-01-01,ind_1,NaN,NaN,NaN,ind_1
2,2014-01-02,ind_1,NaN,ind_3,NaN,ind_1
2,2014-01-02,ind_1,NaN,ind_3,NaN,ind_3
3,2014-01-03,ind_1,ind_2,ind_3,NaN,ind_1
3,2014-01-03,ind_1,ind_2,ind_3,NaN,ind_2
3,2014-01-03,ind_1,ind_2,ind_3,NaN,ind_3
```

Any tips or tricks are most appreciated as always!

Comment: Why did you rollback the edit to your question?

Comment: See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) about NOT adding titular tags, because the tags are already appended to the title internally in SO's database (for better indexing by google). Also, "Python PANDAS" is kinda grotesque a prefix substring. And the numpy tag has nothing to do with your question either.

Comment: I actually let my edit go through to fix the id field in the example data.  Then someone proposed changing the question title format to something I found less helpful which I accidentally accepted and then I rolled back.

Comment: Oh, I see you explanation.  I will keep that in mind moving forward for naming conventions.

Comment: Alright, no worries, and glad you understand :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a `merge` based solution using `melt`/`stack` to build the RHS.

```
v = (df.drop('date', 1)
       .melt('id')
       .drop('variable', 1)
       .dropna()
       .rename({'value' : 'ind_all'}, axis=1)
)

df.merge(v)

   id        date  ind_1  ind_2  ind_3  ind_4 ind_all
0   1  2014-01-01  ind_1    NaN    NaN    NaN   ind_1
1   2  2014-01-02  ind_1    NaN  ind_3    NaN   ind_1
2   2  2014-01-02  ind_1    NaN  ind_3    NaN   ind_3
3   3  2014-01-03  ind_1  ind_2  ind_3    NaN   ind_1
4   3  2014-01-03  ind_1  ind_2  ind_3    NaN   ind_2
5   3  2014-01-03  ind_1  ind_2  ind_3    NaN   ind_3
```

Or,

```
df.merge(df.drop('date', 1)
           .set_index('id')
           .stack()
           .reset_index(1, drop=True)
           .to_frame('ind_all'), 
         left_on='id', 
         right_index=True
)

   id        date  ind_1  ind_2  ind_3  ind_4 ind_all
0   1  2014-01-01  ind_1    NaN    NaN    NaN   ind_1
1   2  2014-01-02  ind_1    NaN  ind_3    NaN   ind_1
1   2  2014-01-02  ind_1    NaN  ind_3    NaN   ind_3
2   3  2014-01-03  ind_1  ind_2  ind_3    NaN   ind_1
2   3  2014-01-03  ind_1  ind_2  ind_3    NaN   ind_2
2   3  2014-01-03  ind_1  ind_2  ind_3    NaN   ind_3
```

Comment: Thanks for your great solution and prompt response.  I'll check which runs faster for me.